# Duplicate key value Error when updating a lot of data

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I want to save a lot of data in the database (PostgreSQL 12 and the Entity Framework Core (C#)) I get the following exceptions:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (197ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?', @p1='?', @p2='?' (DbType = DateTimeOffset), @p3='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "FileInfos" ("FileId", "FileName", "LastModifiedDateTime", "Path")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
  An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'PostgreSQLConnect.ContextModels.WebhookContext'.
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
   ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_FileInfos 
    Severity: FEHLER
      SqlState: 23505
      MessageText: double key value violates unique constraint »PK_FileInfos«
      Detail: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
      SchemaName: public
      TableName: FileInfos
      ConstraintName: PK_FileInfos
      File: d:\pginstaller_12.auto\postgres.windows-x64\src\backend\access\nbtree\nbtinsert.c
      Line: 570
      Routine: _bt_check_unique
```

Some data needs to be updated, some needs to be created first. This method works for some data, but if I add more than one at a time, I get the exception mentioned above.

```
    private async Task SaveFileInfos(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        var foundFileInfo = _context.FileInfos.
        Where(f => f.FileId == fileInfo.FileId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (foundFileInfo == null)
        {
            await _context.FileInfos.AddAsync(fileInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            foundFileInfo.FileName = fileInfo.FileName;
            foundFileInfo.LastModifiedDateTime = fileInfo.LastModifiedDateTime;
            foundFileInfo.Path = fileInfo.Path;
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

The entity class:

```
    public class FileInfo : IFileInfo
    {

    [Key]
    public string FileId {get; set;}

    public string FileName {get; set;}

    public DateTimeOffset? LastModifiedDateTime {get; set;}

    public string Path {get; set;}
    }
```

The context class:

```
   public class WebhookContext : DbContext
   {
    public WebhookContext(DbContextOptions<WebhookContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<FileInfo> FileInfos { get; set; }
    }
```

The loop that calls the save method:

```
 private async Task ConvertAndSaveFiles(IDriveItemDeltaCollectionPage files)
  { 

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
         await SaveFileInfos(file.Name, file.Id, file.LastModifiedDateTime,
                    file.ParentReference.Path);
    }
           
  }
```

BTW: The Id has already been generated by another application and is 34 characters long.

What mistake did I make as a beginner?  :-)

Comment: You are mixing Sync and Async, try awaiting `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Don't I also have to change the entity class ?

Comment: Why do you use `AddAsync`?

Comment: Since the method in which the loop is also async, I thought that you also have to add the data via AddAsync.

Comment: Or should I only use add ? Or should I only use add ? So without async in the database methods ?

Comment: Don't mix sync and async, try with everything async

Comment: Please clarify the repro scenario (what do you mean by "if I add more than one at a time"). Also, since the PK is string, there might be differences between db and client (C#) string comparison rules (for instance, casing), so take a look at the failing item data "FileId" property and the database table - it could really be a duplicate.

Comment: `AddAsync` should only be used for special cases, see the docs.

Comment: @GertArnold The problem is, I use the MS Graph SDK which uses async calls and I want to write the results of the graph requests to the database, so I thought I would use addAsync etc.

Comment: Not everything in an async method has to be awaitable. Again, `AddAsync` shouldn't be used just because it's async.

Comment: @GertArnold I have undone everything asynchronous but the error still remains I get the Ids (from newly created files) from MS Graph.

Comment: Perhaps you should check whether the table exists and whether the user account you are using has access to the table. You can even try to run the query yourself from SQL Management Studio to see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use **FirstOrDefaultAsync**
- *Where* clause is redundant, you can remove it as well

```
    private async Task SaveFileInfos(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        //update your code to use FirstOrDefaultAsync
        var foundFileInfo = await _context.FileInfos
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.FileId == fileInfo.FileId);

        if (foundFileInfo == null)
        {
            await _context.FileInfos.AddAsync(fileInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            foundFileInfo.FileName = fileInfo.FileName;
            foundFileInfo.LastModifiedDateTime = fileInfo.LastModifiedDateTime;
            foundFileInfo.Path = fileInfo.Path;
        }

       // move this outside the for loop.
       // this will round trip to Db in EVERY fileInfo, not an optimal solution.
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
    }
```

- Consider calling the *await _context.SaveChangesAsync();* **outside the for loop**

```
 private async Task ConvertAndSaveFiles(IDriveItemDeltaCollectionPage files)
  { 

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
         await SaveFileInfos(file.Name, file.Id, file.LastModifiedDateTime,
                    file.ParentReference.Path);
    }

    // this will save everything to Db in just 1 round trip
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned this problem occurs when you are writing to database a lot, the problem might be how are you calling SaveFileInfos(FileInfo fileInfo) method (calling from parallel loop?) if that's the case your foundFileInfo call won't catch duplicates.

Also consider avoiding SaveChangesAsync inside a loop.

Comment: The loop was added to the question

Comment: But why can't foundFileInfo call catch duplicates ?